# How to separate string and number with decimal in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this string value

```
$str="1231B1lB1.1lS1iC1C2.5";
```

I would like to separate string and number with decimal. Here's current code

```
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]+|\d+/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

It working fine if the string has no "."
Can anyone please suggest how to make it works with "." ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Turn it around. First digits with dots, then letters: `[0-9\.]+|\w`

Comment: Hi, I expected to get

$matches[0]= 1231
$matches[1]= B
$matches[2]= 1
$matches[3]= lB
$matches[4]= 1.1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it almost works as what I want but in this example, iC should be in the same array. How can I get that?

Comment: Try `\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[^\W\d]+` https://regex101.com/r/L4SHsk/1

Answer (score 1):

You could match:

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `|` Or
- `[^\W\d]+` match 1+ word characters without digits using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L4SHsk/1)

If you only want to match chars A-Za-z, you could use the character class `[A-Za-z]+`